# Leaflet bindPopup and SQL Queries

Tags: popup, leaflet

I am using phpMyadmin to store my database and I would like to insert 2 columns of data onto the bind popup  and the code is below

```
.bindPopup(healthcare[i][0])
.bindPopup(healthcare][i][3])
```

My aim is to insert the 2 columns of data into one popup.
Do any of you know how to help me with this problem? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The second call actually overwrites the first one. You would need to concatenate results, e.g. like this:

```
.bindPopup(healthcare[i][0] + ' ' + healthcare][i][3]);
```

You would probably want something more sophisticated than that, e.g. with HTML tags, etc.